# Has there (yet) been lawsuits due to smart contract bugs?

Tags: smart-contract-wallets

I was reading up on smart contract vulnerabilities.

So, in case someone deposits Eth to my smart contract, say as a Auction Bid. Then someone else exploits a bug to empty the smart contract balance. Is the smart contract deployer open to a lawsuit?

Has any blockchain related lawsuits happened yet?

Answer (score 0):

That's a massive grey area with Decentralized Finance. Without regulations it's hard to lay blame on to any one party.

I am assuming you are speaking about the recent scams stemming from smart contracts on the OpenSeaShared Contract. With this there has not been much fall back, other than on Twitter at the moment. I am unsure if there have been any lawsuits either.

If you want to learn more about anti-phishing, I urge you to read some stuff from Harry Denley on MyCrypto https://blog.mycrypto.com/author/harry/